# How to calculate the eigenvector?

Tags: pca, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I've been struggling to solve this math problem for two days...

[image]

So I calculated the mean of all samples (0,0).

Put it into the equation and got V as

\begin{array}
{rrr}
4 & 2  \\
2 & 2 
\end{array}

Then I tried to get $$ \lambda $$ for the eigenvalue and got an equation as
$$ 4-6\lambda+\lambda^2 =0 $$

So I got two values for lambda.

But everything stopped here, I couldn't go any further.

Could anyone please help me with this？ Or probably tell me where I did wrong in this problem? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Start from the definition. How are eigenvectors defined?